# Errors occuring while using Observables in angular 2+

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I want  all my functions in my angular.ts file to continue executing repeatedly to get real-time data on the UI. So i used Observables. But i face an sql error.

The issue here is an error -

[1]

```
 mySQL Error - Too many connections .
```

What is the solution to the errors.I have included angular as well as node code

code -

**component.ts**

```
    export class DashboardComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
    Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(x => {
    this.viewEntireData()
    });

     }


   viewEntireData() {

   console.log("INSIDE viewEntireData()")

   var url = config.url;
   var port = config.port;


      this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
      "/dashboard/entireSuccess/", this.emptyObj
       , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
         localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
      .map(resultSuccess1 => this.resultSuccess1 = 
        resultSuccess1.json(), )
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {



        this.entireSuccessResult = this.resultSuccess1.length;

      });

      });


        }

        }
```

**NODEJS Code -**

```
  function entireSuccess() {

   var sqlQuery = `select * from TRANSACTION_PAYLOAD where 
   INTERFACE_NAME = 'Experian' AND (STATUS ='SUCCESS_RESPONSE')`

var deferred = Q.defer();



    var host = config.host;
    var user = config.user;
    var password = config.password;
    var database = config.database;



   var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database
     });



   con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

    con.query(sqlQuery,
        function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
            // if (err) throw err;

            console.log(result);
            deferred.resolve(result);
        });
     });
    return deferred.promise; 
    con.close();
    con.close();


     }
```

Comment: Those errors look like they're from the backend...

Comment: what makes you think that the error is related to that code snippet?

Comment: HI Jota, thanks for replying. I have no idea where is the error coming from. I have included my nodejs file code. Please check. I have even closed the connection. Still i get Too many connections error

Comment: @Techdive Code after return statements is unreachable, so it can't execute your `con.close()`

Comment: so if i put con.close() before  return deferred.promise ...will my code work ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will fix everything, but it is certainly necessary if you want to close your connections

Comment: ok . thanks. i will look into it. And if any queries ..then i will inquire

Comment: @user184994 and Jota . I am unable to solve the issue. Because as i put con.close() or con.end() before -->  return deferred.promise; . I donot get the output . Is there any other way to close the connection. Or any link that would help.